# Mongoose: Find and update one document that contains min value

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, find

I'm trying to find a document in a Mongo collection that contains a min value, and then update its status.

This is my collection. This collection could have much more documents in it. In this example, I'll only give you 3 documents.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d44f733fa2a2f021dbbd2d6"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5d3b4766e14bc7085e74c4e7"),
    "items" : 13,
    "status" : 2,
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d44f76efa2a2f021dbbd2d7"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5d3b4766e14bc7085e74c4e7"),
    "items" : 10,
    "status" : 2,
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d44f76efa2a2f021a5b64d"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5d3b4766e14bc7085e74c4e7"),
    "items" : 15,
    "status" : 2,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to find and update the status to `1` of the document that has the minimum amount of items, which is in this case the second document with 10 items.

Is there any way to do it only using one query? I've been trying to do it using `findOneAndUpdate` using the option `sort` but it doesn't  work. It seems it is not a valid query.

Any ideas?

Comment: how you want to update value? by query or using code? if using code mention language binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the aggregate function we can set the value. first, we have to sort the document based on `items` field in ascending order then limit the output one. Then with `$set` operator, we can change the value.

Please find the below Query:

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort : { items : 1} },
     { $limit : 1 },
     {$set : {"status" : 1}}
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To update status with minimum items

Try this

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { $set : { "status" : 1 } },
   { sort : { "items" : 1 } }
)
```